# Texture uses UV, Pixel effect uses Object Texture Coords

Tags: materials, uv, vector-mapping, pixel-art

My goal here is to be able to rotate the object, and have the *image* rotate with the UV map, But have the *pixel effect* rotate relative to an outside object, but given the setup i'm using I don't know how to get it to work[image]

[image]

[image]

If there's a better pixel effect that supports what I need that works too.

From what i found, I Basically need a setup that gives a pixel effect to a UV Texture coordinate like this:

[image]
[image]

But I want the Pixels Stay upright relative to an empty (Or the world)
I've Tried for multiple hours experimenting with literally every combination of nodes I can think of that could work, But I'm not *amazing* with math.

If anyone trying to solve this needs any more info on the problem, let me know

Thanks!

Comment: So you mean, you want to keep the rotation even when it's rotated?

Comment: I need the image itself to rotate with the plane, but the pixel effect to rotate with an empty that i will keep upright, or the world

Comment: Oh alright, okay

Comment: Wow, this confused me. I believe it's possible! I can't figure it out for now but there's better pixel effect: https://imgur.com/a/aBkCwR3

Comment: Ah yeah I figured out that pixel texture too, But didn't really help me get the effect to work any better. Thanks for trying though, I have no idea why something so seemingly simple is near impossible apparently

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

Two parts in this node tree:

- Find the rotation of the empty

[image]

This is done using two radial gradient textures, one from the UVs one from the empty and get the difference.

As the gradient goes from 0 to 1, there is a discontinuity at the limit. To compensate that we look if this is a negative value and if it is set it back positive adding 1.

Then map from 0, 1 to 0, 2*pi in order to have the angle.

- Use this rotation before snaping

[image]

From the angle above, rotate, snap and rotate back.

**Note**: set the image texture interpolation to closest as snap node may make glitches if not (this is not done in the file below).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Woah, that's clever :O

Comment: YES THATS PERFECT! There was a little bit of a graphical error in EEVEE which had me worried, but changing the image interpolation to Closest instead of Linear fixed it

Comment: Yes snap alone (no other calculation) does that without closest.